# Using characteristic function to show a random variable cannot have a given distribution.

Tags: probability

I have been reading up on characteristic functions for random variables and came across the following question:

> "Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and identically distributed random
>   variables. Show that $X$ and $Y$ cannot be chosen so that $X-Y$ has
>   the uniform distribution on the interval $(-1, 1)$."

I have approached the problem as follows:

Since both $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, they must also have the same characteristic function, call it $\phi(t)$. 
Thusly, $X-Y$ has characteristic function $-\phi(t)^2$.

I know that the characteristic function associated with the uniform distribution is given by $$\phi_{U(-1, 1)} = \cases{\frac{e^{it} - e^{-it}}{2it}&if $t\neq$0\\\\1 & if $t = 0$ }$$

This is equivalent to 
$$\phi_{U(-1, 1)} = \cases{\frac{\sin(t)}{t}&if $t\neq$0\\\\1 & if $t = 0$ }$$

But from here, I am stuck trying to show that $-\phi(t)^2$ cannot equal $\phi_{U(-1, 1)}$.

How can I go about showing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your characteristic function computation isn't quite right: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with characteristic function $\phi$, then
$$\phi_{X-Y}(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{it(X-Y)}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]\mathbb{E}[e^{-itY}]=\phi(t)\phi(-t)=|\phi(t)|^2$$
since $\phi(-t)=\overline{\phi(t)}$.

In particular, $\phi_{X-Y}(t)$ is always non-negative, whereas the characteristic function of the uniform distribution takes on both positive and negative values.

Comment: +1 though your final step $\phi(t)\phi(-t)=|\phi(t)|^2$ uses the Hermitian property of characteristic functions, which might be worth mentioning explicitly

Comment: Sure, added it.