# Difference between two iid random variables is not uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was doing this problem about two i.i.d. random variables:

> Let $X$ and $Z$ be i.i.d. random variables. Show that $X-Z$ has not uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}[-1,1]$.

To prove this, we can consider a random variable $U$ with uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}[-1,1]$, and see if the characteristic functions of $X-Z$ and $U$ are the same. Let $\varphi_{V}$ be the characteristic function of some random variable $V$. As $X$ and $Z$ are identically distributed, then $\varphi_{X}=\varphi_{Z}=\varphi$.

Using that $X$ and $Z$ are i.i.d. we can calculate $\varphi_{X-Z}$:

$\varphi_{X-Z}(t)=E\left[e^{it(X-Z)}\right]=E\left[e^{itX}e^{-itZ}\right]=E\left[e^{itX}\right]E\left[e^{-itZ}\right]=\varphi_{X}(t)\varphi_{Z}(t)=\varphi(t)\varphi(-t)$

And the characteristic function of $U$ is the fourier transform of a pulse (the sinc function):

$\varphi_{U}(t)=E\left[e^{itU}\right]=\text{sinc}(t)$

Then the problem is to prove that $\text{sinc}(t)\neq \varphi(t)\varphi(-t)$ for every function $\varphi$, but how can we prove this? Thank you very much.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006017/using-characteristic-function-to-show-a-random-variable-cannot-have-a-given-dist

Comment: Thank you! But why $\phi(t)\phi(-t)=|\phi(t)|^{2}$?

Comment: $\phi(-t)=\overline{\phi(t)}$ since $e^{-itx}=\overline{e^{itx}}$ when $t$ and $x$ are real numbers.

Comment: Solved [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346269/).